# How can I find the max sum of 5 values in this dataframe, but no values can be in the same row or column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
[[-9.92, 23.04, -6.06, -0.72, 21.32],

 [54.98, 15.58, 51.66, 54.1, 43.76],

 [49.22, 5.68, 25.24, 31.8, 43.3],

 [32.1, 15.12, 9.38, 28.96, 40.14],

 [13.2, 10.36, 12.44, -12.02, 15.8]]
```

I have a pandas data frame using this data structure. I would like to find the maximum sum of 5 values in the data frame, but the values cannot be in the same column or row. For instance, values of `[9.92, 15.58, 25.24, 28.96, 15.8]` would be permissible, but `[9.92, 15.58, 25.24, 28.96, 40.14]` & `[9.92, 15.58, 25.24, 28.96, -12.02]` would not be.

Ideally I would like to generate a list of lists from this data frame that fits my criteria and then find the maximum from there.

```
[{'Stephen Curry': -9.92,
  'Buddy Hield': 23.04,
  'Duncan Robinson': -6.06,
  'Damian Lillard': -0.72,
  'Joe Harris': 21.32},
 {'Stephen Curry': 54.98,
  'Buddy Hield': 15.58,
  'Duncan Robinson': 51.66,
  'Damian Lillard': 54.1,
  'Joe Harris': 43.76},
 {'Stephen Curry': 49.22,
  'Buddy Hield': 5.68,
  'Duncan Robinson': 25.24,
  'Damian Lillard': 31.8,
  'Joe Harris': 43.3},
 {'Stephen Curry': 32.1,
  'Buddy Hield': 15.12,
  'Duncan Robinson': 9.38,
  'Damian Lillard': 28.96,
  'Joe Harris': 40.14},
 {'Stephen Curry': 13.2,
  'Buddy Hield': 10.36,
  'Duncan Robinson': 12.44,
  'Damian Lillard': -12.02,
  'Joe Harris': 15.8}]
```

Comment: your dataframe contains arrays? or are these individual columns? kindly share your data as a dictionary : ``df.head(10).to_dict('records')``

Comment: I just converted it to a dictionary. Apologies for the formatting, this is my first time posting a question to stackoverflow so I am very unfamiliar with how to properly format on here.

Comment: no worries. Kindly add your expected output dataframe as well

Comment: This is a cool problem but it's O(n!), so there is no "nice" solution. Some strategies, like branch-and-bound or meet-in-the-middle could help, but the "best" approach will be domain-dependent or ultimately subjective

Comment: The output would be a list of 5 numbers that follows my criteria and generates the maximum possible sum. Ideally I would be able to make a list of lists of all possible ways to get 5 numbers that follow my criteria and then find the sum of all these lists in order to find the list that has the maximum sum.

Comment: @Marat Thanks for the advice! Can you please elaborate on what an O(n!) problem is and how it directly applies to this?

Comment: @AleksandrPrystupa it means the complexity of the problem grows very fast with every extra row/column ([wiki:NP-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_problem)). It is possible to solve it for a small input like this, but will be VERY challenging for any non-trivial dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  This particular instance is small enough to brute force.

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
    [[-9.92, 23.04, -6.06, -0.72, 21.32],
     [54.98, 15.58, 51.66, 54.1, 43.76],
     [49.22, 5.68, 25.24, 31.8, 43.3],
     [32.1, 15.12, 9.38, 28.96, 40.14],
     [13.2, 10.36, 12.44, -12.02, 15.8]]
)

best_perm = None
best_sum = -np.inf
for perm in permutations(range(5)):
    s = sum([arr[perm[i],i] for i in range(5)])
    if s > best_sum:
        best_sum = s
        best_perm = perm
```

the result

`best_sum` = 178.94

`best_perm` = (2, 0, 4, 1, 3)

meaning the best solution is given by choosing 3rd row for column 1, 1st row for column 2, 5th row for column 3, 2nd row for column 4, and 4th row for column 5.

Generalising the problem to a large number of columns and rows could be intractable, in which case you could try [integer programming with PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/)

Comment: I'd second Pulp. Maybe it's worth expanding into an answer

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49490423/formulating-an-linear-programming-assignment-in-pulp

Comment: @Riley Thank you so much! Luckily, I will only be dealing with 5 x 5 arrays in this project. You've saved my nba data science project, much appreciated!